# .htaccess Remove filename from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove: `"site.php"` from my url:s, which look like 
`"example.com/custom-foldername/site.php"`, so the url:s would look like `"example.com/custom-foldername"`

Currently it's not working at all. Basically my site just doesn't change the url. I know that the `.htaccess` file is being read, because if i write junk code in it, it gives error 500.

Here is my current `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^site\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: forward `/` in `/site.php` removes `/custom-foldername`

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? In the document root, or in the `/custom-foldername` subdirectory?

Comment: "my site just doesn't change the url" - you should be "changing the URL" in your application, not in `.htaccess`?

Comment: @MrWhite My .htaccess is in the root directory

Comment: Is `site.php` present in _all_ your URLs? Please include examples of the URLs being requested in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I solved this my myself while ago, but forgot to update

So, i found the [solution](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747718-How-can-I-control-my-directory-indexes-with-an-htaccess-file-) and here's my current .htaccess file, if someone is ever having the same problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex site.php site.html
```

When user "asks" for folder directory (example.com/cats) apache looks for "site.php or site.html" files inside it. (example.com/cats/site.php) If it finds either on of them it displays it to the user as (example.com/cats). If either file isn't found it gives normal "404 not found error"

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a *front-controller pattern* - it rewrites every request for non-existent files to `/site.php` in the document root (not `/custom-foldername/site.php`).

And nor will a `RewriteRule` *pattern* like `^site\.php$` match a request like `/custom-foldername` if the `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

> I'm trying to remove `site.php` from my URLs...

From *all* your URLs? Is `site.php` present in *all* your URLs? So, `site.php` is your *front-controller*?

If `site.php` really is your front-controller then try something like the following instead:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /custom-foldername

RewriteRule site\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ site.php [L]
```

This rewrites everything that doesn't map to a physical file or directory to `/custom-foldername/site.php`.

Comment: My current url:s look like this:
`example.com/cats/site.php`
`example.com/dogs/site.php`
etc...

I would like for the visible part of the url to change to:
`example.com/cats`
`example.com/dogs`
etc...
but they should still get their data from the original file.

I know how to do this with multiple RewriteRules, but i dont know how to make it with regex.